# Testing localStorage have been called

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I'm trying to run a test using **ts-jest** and **testing-library/react** verifing if localStorage.setItem function have been called when login function is executed. This sentences is in some provider component.

Here is the provider component code:

```
export const AuthProvider: FC<{ children: React.ReactNode }> = ({ children }) => {

    const [authState, dispatch] = useReducer(AuthReducer, initialState, init);

    const onLoginAction = (userLogged: User) => {
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(userLogged));

        dispatch({
            type: AuthTypes.login,
            payloads: userLogged
        })
    }

    const onLogoutAction = () => {
        //Something else
    }


    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ authState, onLoginAction, onLogoutAction }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

**onLoginAction** function save data to localstorage and execute a dispatch.
This is my testing code:

```
describe('testing AuthProvider', () => {

    const initialState: stateProps = {
        logged: false
    }

    test('should store user and change state to login', () => {

        Storage.prototype.setItem = jest.fn();

        const onLoginAction = jest.fn();
        const onLogoutAction = jest.fn();

        const context: contextProps = {
            authState: initialState,
            onLoginAction,
            onLogoutAction,
        }

        const userLogged: User = {
            username: 'Pepito123',
            name: 'Pepito',
            lastName: '',
            githubUrl: ''
        }

        render(
            <AuthContext.Provider value={context}>
                <button aria-label='loginButton' onClick={() => onLoginAction(userLogged)}>login</button>
            </AuthContext.Provider>
        )

        const button = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'loginButton' }) as HTMLButtonElement;

        fireEvent.click(button)
        expect(onLoginAction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(userLogged);
        expect(localStorage.setItem).toHaveBeenCalled(); //no reconoce que se esta llamando el localstorage (revisar luego) 

    })

})
```

Console show that **localStorage.setItem** never called.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkuqM.png)

when execute the fireEvent. I expect all the code inside **onLoginAction** executed (include local store function and dispatch ). I need something else inside the test?

Comment: could you please provide more information on how teh local storage is imported? you may need to spy on the local storage module

Answer (score 0):

You can use jest spy for this:

```
jest.spyOn(localStorage, 'setItem');


expect(localStorage.setItem).toBeCalledWith('fakeUser','your json string');
```